# How to use POST and GET method in the same page, and pass all variables to next page by pressing button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

In current code, I have POST and GET method on the same php page(delivery.php) as shown below.
What I would like to achieve is that passing following items1-5 to next page(payment.php) by pressing button (Go to payment page).

item1; request (this is coming from previous page)
item2; name (user's input)
item3; shippingfee (shown in span tag in the code, and this is the value returned back from shipping.php by GET method)
item4; address(user's input)
item5; email(user's input)

How can I achieve that?

delivery.php

```
<?php
  $request = $_POST['request'];
?>

<html>
....
  <form name="aaa" method="POST" action="payment.php">
    <input name="name"></input>
  </form>
  <form name="bbb" method="GET" action="shipping.php">
    <select id="country" name="countryshipping">
      <option value="null" select="selected">default</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <form name="ccc" method="POST" action="payment.php">
    <input name="address"></input>
    <input name="email"></input>
  </form>
  ....
  <div>
    <span id="shippingfee"></span>
  </div>
  ....
  <form ????????>
    <button type="submit">Go to payment page</button>
  </form>
  ....
```

---

Solution

I could manage to achieve what I wanted to do. Sharing my code:

delivery.php

```
<?php
  $request = $_POST['request'];
?>

<html>
....
  <form name="aaa" method="POST" action="payment.php">
    <input name="name"></input>
    <select id="country" name="countryshipping">
      <option value="null" select="selected">default</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input name="address"></input>
    <input name="email"></input>
  </form>
  ....
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingfee" id="shippingfee2"><span id="shippingfee"></span>
  </div>
  ....
    <button type="submit">Go to payment page</button>
  </form>
  ....
```

Payment.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$country = $_POST['countryshipping'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$shippingfee = $_POST['shippingfee'];
?>
```

In addition to above codes, I added one line in jQuery

```
document.getElementById("totalfees2").value = value; // "this value is the same value which is stored in id="shippingfee""
```

Comment: You can not do this. Post is on submit only and you cant keep submitting more and more. You will have to find a way to store information between steps (hint: sessions).

Comment: why not instead just combine all of the forms set them all to POST and then parse through in the PHP based on the submitted fields? this way you actually submit all the data to the same place and get the right returns. You can most likely combine your shipping.php with payment.php, but I don't know that 100%.

Comment: >Martijn, thanks! I found a way :) >Cayce thanks! I think my final code looks similar to what you have in your mind. I will post my code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="script.php?foo=bar" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="baz" value="qux">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

echo $_POST['baz']; // "qux"
echo $_GET['foo']; // "baz"
```

Note that the other way around doesn't work. You can't have a `get` method form, and get POST data submitted as well.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I was trying your way to modify my code. However, before reaching your level, I could somehow achieve what I would like to do. Very much appreciated your help and I will post my code later.

Answer (score 2):

$_REQUEST will deliver all of the get and post vars.

```
echo $_REQUEST['baz']; // "qux"
echo $_REQUEST['foo']; // "baz"
```